# Grouping and aggregation based on a specific condition

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, group-by, conditional-statements, aggregate-functions

My result set from a query looks like this

```
trackingnumber   type         price 
------------------------------------------
12799467         AVRM         674.0536
12799467         AVRM         860.7415
12799467         PRICESTD     200.00
12799468         PRICESTD     590.85
12799469         PRICESTD     800
12799470         PRICESTD     640
12799471         PRICESTD     160
12799472         PRICESTD     2080
12799473         PRICESTD     354.3779
```

I want to group this by the `trackingnumber` and in cases where the count of grouped result set is greater than 1 return the `SUM` of all the `price` which has `type` as `AVRM` else return the individual price as it is. If the count
is more that zero and the none of them has `type` AVRM then it's total price would be null

The expected result would be this

```
trackingnumber  Total Price
-----------------------------------------
12799467        1534.7951 --sum of price excluding 200
12799468        590.85
12799469        800
12799470        640
12799471        160
12799472        2080
12799473        354.3779
```

I couldn't think of a way to get this done except for grouping by `trackingnumber` and checking for `type` by using `case` statement in the `select` part but that I believe would not work since we do not group by `type`

I'm not sure if this can be achieved using a single query.

Comment: what if there is another row like `12799468         PRICESTD     100` Which `price` would u return then?

Comment: and also what if where is another row like '123 AVRM 100` As this is the only record for that `trackingnumber` would u return price or not.

Comment: @Utsav - if we read the problem literally, if there is only one row for a trackingnumber, then "return the individual price as it is" - the "else" clause in the OP's problem statement makes no reference to `AVRM` or `not AVRM`. But the first question stands: what if for a trackingnumber there are multiple rows, none of which have type `AVRM`? Or is that not possible in the real-life data?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can be done in a single query.

```
with sample_data ( tracking_Number, "TYPE", price ) as
(  
SELECT 12799467,'AVRM',674.0536 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12799467,'AVRM',860.7415 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12799467,'PRICESTD',200.00 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12799468,'PRICESTD',590.85 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12799469,'PRICESTD',800 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12799470,'PRICESTD',640 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12799471,'PRICESTD',160 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12799472,'PRICESTD',2080 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12799473,'PRICESTD',354.3779 FROM DUAL )
SELECT tracking_number, 
       case when count(*) > 1 THEN 
          sum(decode("TYPE",'AVRM',price,null)) ELSE 
          sum(price) END price
from sample_data
group by tracking_number
order by tracking_Number;
```

Answer (score 0):

For example next solution. I add condition to exlude rows with type not equla 'AVRM' if rows with 'AVRM' exests

```
with s (trackingnumber ,type        ,price)
as (
select 12799467,'AVRM',674.0536 from dual union all
select 12799467        ,'AVRM',         860.7415  from dual union all
select 12799467        ,'PRICESTD',     200.00  from dual union all
select 12799468         ,'PRICESTD',       590.85  from dual union all
select 12799469         ,'PRICESTD',       800  from dual union all
select 12799470         ,'PRICESTD',       640  from dual union all
select 12799471         ,'PRICESTD',       160  from dual union all
select 12799472         ,'PRICESTD',       2080  from dual union all
select 12799473         ,'PRICESTD',       354.3779  from dual )
select trackingnumber, 
       sum(price)
 from (select s.*,rownum as rn from s
        where not exists (select null
                        from s subs
                where s.trackingnumber = subs.trackingnumber
                  and s.type != 'AVRM'
                  and subs.type = 'AVRM')
       )
 group by trackingnumber,
          case when type = 'AVRM' then 0 else rn end;
```